# Intersection of intersection of families of sets is intersection of union of families of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am going through Velleman's "How to prove it" and I am stuck on exercise 13b of section 2.3, where I have to show:
$$(\cap \mathcal{F})\cap (\cap \mathcal{G})=\cap(\mathcal{F}\cup \mathcal{G})$$
I don't see how the union comes into place here. Here's what I have got:
$$x\in (\cap \mathcal{F})\cap (\cap \mathcal{G})$$
$$x\in (\cap \mathcal{F})\land x\in(\cap \mathcal{G})$$
$$(\forall i \in I (x\in A_i)) \land (\forall i \in I (x\in B_i))$$
$$\forall i \in I ((x\in A_i) \land (x\in B_i))$$
$$x\in \cap (A_i\cap B_i)$$
Something must be wrong here, somehow the i dissappeared. Hope someone can help.

Comment: There's no requirement that $\cal F$ and $\cal G$ be indexed by the same set $I$. I imagine not making this assumption will lead you down a better track. But also note that just because you followed _some_ sequence of steps that doesn't lead to your goal doesn't mean that there isn't _another_ sequence of steps that does.

Comment: @DanDoel Ok, let me give it a try. I will give it another try tomorrow. I have some work to do.

Comment: I don't believe the statement is true as written. Take $\mathcal F = \{ \{1\} \}$ and $\mathcal G = \{ \{2\} \}$ (both families consist of just one set); then the left-hand side is $\{1\}\cap\{2\}=\emptyset$ while the right-hand side is $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: @Greg Martin: In that case, $\mathcal{F}\cup\mathcal{G} = \{\{1\}\}\cup\{\{2\}\} = \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, so $\cap(\mathcal{F}\cup\mathcal{G}) = \cap\{ \{1\},\{2\}\} = \{1\}\cap\{2\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: ah I see I misinterpreted the notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $y\in \cap\mathcal{F}$ as
$$y\in\cap\mathcal{F}\iff \forall A\in\mathcal{F} (y\in A).$$
This can also be expressed as:
$$y\in\cap\mathcal{F}\iff \forall A(A\in\mathcal{F}\to y\in A).$$
And likewise
$$z\in\cap \mathcal{G}\iff \forall A(A\in\mathcal{G}\to z\in A).$$

So we have:
$$\begin{align*}
x\in(\cap \mathcal{F})\cap(\cap\mathcal{G}) &\iff (x\in\cap\mathcal{F})\wedge (x\in\cap\mathcal{G})\\
&\iff \Bigl(\forall A(A\in\mathcal{F}\to x\in A)\Bigr)\wedge \Bigl(\forall A(A\in\mathcal{G}\to x\in A)\Bigr)\\
&\iff \forall A\Bigl( (A\in\mathcal{F}\to x\in A)\wedge (A\in\mathcal{G}\to x\in A)\Bigr).
\end{align*}$$
Now here is the key observation: both implications have the same consequent, so we can now use the equivalent
$$(P\to R)\wedge (Q\to R) \equiv (P\vee Q)\to R.$$
This can be easily verified: since $X\to Y$ is equivalent to $\neg(X)\vee Y$, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
(P\to R)\wedge (Q\to R) &\iff (\neg(P)\vee R)\wedge (\neg(Q)\vee R)\\
&\iff (\neg(P)\wedge \neg(Q))\vee R\tag{1}\\
&\iff \neg(P\vee Q)\vee R\tag{2}\\
&\iff (P\vee Q)\to R,
\end{align*}$$
where (1) holds because $\vee$ distributes over $\wedge$, and (2) is an application of De Morgan's Law.

So we have:
$$\begin{align*}
x\in (\cap \mathcal{F})\cap(\cap\mathcal{G}) &\iff \forall A \Bigl((A\in \mathcal{F}\to x\in A)\wedge (A\in\mathcal{G}\to x\in A)\Bigr)\\
&\iff \forall A \Bigl( \bigl(A\in\mathcal{F})\vee (A\in\mathcal{G})\bigr)\to x\in A\Bigr)\\
&\iff \forall A\Bigl( (A\in\mathcal{F}\cup\mathcal{G}) \to (x\in A)\Bigr).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Wow that is a really good answer! Thanks!